# Mongoose Validation error in all the fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a Mongoose Schema ready but when I call it with my api it gives out validation errors in all of the required fields

this is my schema object

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please use a name']
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please use a valid e-mail'],
        unique : true,
        lowercase: true,
        validator: [validator.isEmail, 'Please provide a valid e-mail']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please provide a password for your profile'],
        minlength: 6
    },

    passwordConfirm: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please confirm your password']
    }
})
```

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

the req. body i sent with the api through JSON is

```
{
    "name": "user1",
    "email": "user1@gmail.com",
    "password": "pass1234",
    "passwordConfirm": "pass1234"
}
```

I was trying to make a new user through the api and model throuth the controller

```
exports.signup = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const newUser = await User.create(req.body)
        console.log('in the newUser');
        res.status(201)
           .json({
            status: 'success',
            data: {
                user: newUser
            } 
            
        }) 

    }catch (err){
        res.status(400).json({
            status: 'fail',
            message: err
        })
    }
}
```

```
then I get the following errors in postman
```

{
"status": "fail",
"message": {
"errors": {
"passwordConfirm": {
"name": "ValidatorError",
"message": "Please confirm your password",
"properties": {
"message": "Please confirm your password",
"type": "required",
"path": "passwordConfirm"
},
"kind": "required",
"path": "passwordConfirm"
},
"password": {
"name": "ValidatorError",
"message": "Please provide a password for your profile",
"properties": {
"message": "Please provide a password for your profile",
"type": "required",
"path": "password"
},
"kind": "required",
"path": "password"
},
"email": {
"name": "ValidatorError",
"message": "Please use a valid e-mail",
"properties": {
"message": "Please use a valid e-mail",
"type": "required",
"path": "email"
},
"kind": "required",
"path": "email"
},
"name": {
"name": "ValidatorError",
"message": "Please use a name",
"properties": {
"message": "Please use a name",
"type": "required",
"path": "name"
},
"kind": "required",
"path": "name"
}
},
"_message": "User validation failed",
"name": "ValidationError",
"message": "User validation failed: passwordConfirm: Please confirm your password, password: Please provide a password for your profile, email: Please use a valid e-mail, name: Please use a name"
}
}

Comment: I'd be making sure that the request.body is json and has the shape you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `required: true` in your schema

If the validation fail, an error will be throw in:

> ```
> const newUser = await User.create(req.body);
> ```

so you need to catch it and return an appropriate message to the user here (no in the model validation)